# Ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java

Выходит ошибка Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0. Не могу поянть, какой элемент в массиве отсутствует, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
package pr;
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class pr12 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            double[][] x;
            double [] y = new double[0];
            int counter = 0;
            int N,M;
            Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("N = ");
            N = inp.nextInt();
            System.out.print("M = ");
            M = inp.nextInt();

            x = new double[N][M]; // N-число строк M-число столбцов
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                    System.out.print("x(" + i + "," + j + ")=");
                    x[i][j] = inp.nextDouble();
                }
            }
            inp.close();

            //вывод матрицы в виде таблицы
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.printf("%6.2f", x[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            //задание
            double [] result = new double [x.length % 2 == 0 ? x.length/2 : x.length/2+1];
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 2) { //четные строки
                boolean isum = false;
                double increase = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                    if ((x[i][j] % 1 == 0)) {
                        isum = true;

                        increase *= x[i][j];
                        y[counter] = increase;
                        counter++;

                    }
                }
                if (!isum)
                    increase = 0;

            }
            //выводим новый массив
            if(counter == 0)
                System.out.println("В матрице в четных строках только дробные числа");
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < counter-1; i++) {
                        System.out.printf("Массив: x(%d) = %1.2f\n", i, y[i]);
                }

        }
}
```

Comment: Ну хорошо бы показать на какой строчке падает

Comment: Что тут понимать. Прямо в сообщении написано, что отсутствует элемент 0. т.е. массив просто-напросто пустой, не содержит ничего.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at pr.pr5.main(pr.java:47)
Это все что у меня выходит

Comment: а в чем ошибка, почему он пустой?

Comment: Оно и неудивительно - если создавать массив нулевой длины, то там ничего и не будет: ``double [] y = new double[0];``

Comment: компилятор сам предлагает так сделать, иначе указывает на y[counter] = increase;  ошибку Variable 'y' might not have been initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если попробовать разбивать на методы и использовать коллекцию вместо массива, дабы не играться с его размером, то все становится проще и рабоает без танцев с бубном))

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pr12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //double[][] x = {{0.1, 0.2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("N = ");
        int N = inp.nextInt();
        System.out.print("M = ");
        int M = inp.nextInt();
        
        double[][] x = new double[N][M]; // N-число строк M-число столбцов
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                System.out.print("x(" + i + "," + j + ")=");
                x[i][j] = inp.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        inp.close();
        
        printAray(x);
        
        Double[] result = convert(x);
        
        //выводим новый массив
        if (result.length == 0) System.out.println("В матрице в четных строках только дробные числа");
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) System.out.printf("Массив: x(%d) = %1.2f\n", i, result[i]);

    }
    
    //вывод матрицы в виде таблицы
    private static void printAray(double[][] arr) {        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%6.2f", arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    private static Double[] convert(double[][] arr) {
        final List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) { //четные строки
            boolean isum = false;
            double increase = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if ((arr[i][j] % 1 == 0)) {
                    isum = true;
                    increase *= arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            if (isum) result.add(increase);
        }
        return result.toArray(new Double[result.size()]);
    }
    
}
```

Аналогично, но без методов (так лучше не делать, но для понимания прикреплю):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pr12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //double[][] x = {{0.1, 0.2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("N = ");
        int N = inp.nextInt();
        System.out.print("M = ");
        int M = inp.nextInt();
        
        double[][] arr = new double[N][M]; // N-число строк M-число столбцов
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                System.out.print("x(" + i + "," + j + ")=");
                arr[i][j] = inp.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        inp.close();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%6.2f", arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        final List<Double> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) { //четные строки
            boolean isum = false;
            double increase = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if ((arr[i][j] % 1 == 0)) {
                    isum = true;
                    increase *= arr[i][j];
                }
            }
            if (isum) results.add(increase);
        }
        Double[] result = results.toArray(new Double[results.size()]);
        
        //выводим новый массив
        if (result.length == 0) System.out.println("В матрице в четных строках только дробные числа");
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) System.out.printf("Массив: x(%d) = %1.2f\n", i, result[i]);

    }
    
}
```

Comment: мне именно нужно сделать без подпрограмм

Comment: @Maria это не подпрограммы, мы даже за пределы класса не вышли. вы можете скопировать эти методы снова в мейн, заменив вызовы методов их кодом и все будет работать. но это неправильно. разбивать логику на методы необходимо

Comment: мне необходимо чтобы было без дополнительных private static,

Comment: Сейчас складывается мнение, что либо тот кто вам эту задачку задал некомпетентен "слегка" либо вы не совсем понимаете то что вам задали. Вы  все то что написал @Дмитрий без каких-либо можете написать и полотном. Но красивее это написано в отдельных методов. И все это без каких-либо "подпорграмм"

Comment: @Maria я добавил в ответ аналогичный код без методов для того, чтобы можно было понять аналогию. но аргумент "мне необходимо" слабенький. кто и зачем вам навязывает такие условия? с такими подходами может лучше на бейсике писать? чем быстрее вы выберетесь из метода мейн и статики, тем лучше для вас))

Comment: я не увидела что вы добавили аналогичный код без методов. спасибо!

Comment: @Maria не за что. делаю это со крипом в сердце и надеюсь, что вы не скопируете бездумно второй вариант, не разобравшись в коде, и только для того, чтобы вы смогли сравнить 2 варианта и на основе этого разобраться с работой методов.  удачи вам